# Data renders twice with different output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Reactjs. When I console log `randomData` I expect the output to be a random text from the `data` and then I want to loop over it. But the result is strange and getting 2 different outputs for each log. When I am out of the `useEffect` I can't even `Array.prototype.map()` over `randomData` or use `String.prototype.split("")`.
PS: I know that If I log inside the `useEffect` it will only render once, but How I get the data(each text) out of the useEffect then I can use it to loop over?

source: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3bd7z

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "hello world"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "hi world"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "hola"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text: "oo"
    }
  ];

  const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomData.length);
    setRandomData(randomData[randomIndex].text);
  }, []);

  console.log(randomData);

  console.log(typeof randomData);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* {data.map(item => console.log((item.text).split("").map(letter => letter)))} */}
      {/* {console.log(typeof randomData)} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: useEffect issue]

Comment: Why are you using ```useEffect``` in the first place?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code in the question. External links to sandboxes can become unavailable rendering the question useless to others. Also do not post screenshots of code. Use code snippets instead.

Comment: `useEffect` runs **after** rendering the component. You are initialising your state with the array in `data`. Then after the first render your effect runs setting a randomly selected string from your data which triggers a re-render. Usually the type of a certain state shouldn't change. What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: @AyushGupta I use it to only render the component once. I have an input field, If I don't use `useEffect` then whenever I change the input the text changes to another random text.

Comment: Thanks for the help both. I think the answer below fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the duplicate output is because you are assigning the `data` to `randomData` initially. React then rerenders (yielding the first console output) and only then calls your useEffect hook.

I would propose you don't use useEffect at all but instead an initialization function for `useState`:

```
const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(()=>{
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    return data[randomIndex].text;
  });
```

This way the data is set during the first render, not after it.

EDIT: If the `data` is coming from an external api, `useEffect` is the right choice. In that case you start fetching in `useEffect` and then set the state once you have the data. Initialize the state to your preferences, (I'd go with `useState(null)`) and handle your render accordingly, because until you have data, `randomData` will not contain anything.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This solved the issue.

Comment: But what If I replace the fixed `data` with a data from external api?

Comment: Great to hear it. Now please add your code to your question to help anyone finding this question in the future, as mentioned in the second comment in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It works just like the code I wrote before. I can render it but I can't `split()` then `map()` over the text because it still renders twice.
I came up with a solution to check if the `randomData` is defined. If so, I could `split()` then `map()` over it.